# Writing to firebase returns exception in thread

Tags: java, firebase

I have been using the Java firebase api and have been having problems writing to it. Originally I was just trying to set a value but I found that I needed a listener to make sure the data is committed before the program ends. I have included my entire main code because I am not sure where the problem lies. The User class is a simple class that holds birth year and full name as defined by the example on the firebase website here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html

```
Firebase rootRef = new Firebase("https://testing-fire.firebaseio.com/");
        Firebase usersRef = rootRef.child("users");

        User alanisawesome = new User("Alan Turing", 1912);
        User gracehop = new User("Grace Hopper", 1906);

        Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<String, User>();
        users.put("alanisawesome", alanisawesome);
        users.put("gracehop", gracehop);

        final CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);
        usersRef.setValue(users, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
                System.out.println("done");
                done.countDown();
            }
        });
        try {
            done.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

The console returns an exception in thread error that looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "TubeSockReader-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/StrictHostnameVerifier
    at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.verifyHost(WebSocket.java:335)
    at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.createSocket(WebSocket.java:319)
    at com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket.run(WebSocket.java:117)
```

The data is not committed to the firebase

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to add anything extra to your Gradle dependencies. Use `firebase-client-jvm` instead of `firebase-client-android`.

Comment: Have the same issue using compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-jvm:2.5.2+'

Comment: @ViktorYakunin You should probably just look into the latest Firebase SDKs? Is there a JVM SDK yet for Firebase 3?

Answer (score 0):

The httpcomponents are probably missing in your classhpath.

Add the following to your maven dependencies :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
    </dependency>
```